# Nested array query using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nested

I'm using mongoose (with nodejs) to make my queries.

I got the following Schemas for my database model (minified ofc):

```
var HistorySchema = new Schema({ 
    status  :   String,
    time    :   Date
});

var TaskSchema   = new Schema({
    game_id             : Schema.Types.ObjectId,    
    history             : [HistorySchema]
}, {collection: 'task'});
```

Now I want to give an example (insertion) for this which I want to use to show my problem and wish:
(Insertion)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5772ca87439632101510fa6b"),
    "history" : 
    [
        {
            "status" : "open",
            "time" : ISODate("2016-06-25T12:17:46.982Z")
        },
        {
            "status" : "complete",
            "time" : ISODate("2016-06-30T12:17:46.982Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

so far so good... Now I have a given date, in this case:

```
ISODate("2016-06-28T12:17:46.982Z")
```

Now I want to get from my collection all TaskSchema objects including matching HistorySchmea objects from the array. So I want to exclude the not matching part in history array.

I tried many things like $pull operation like

```
db.task.find(
{
    "game_id": ObjectId("57711397893a97aa170aa983"),
    "history.time":{
        $lte: ISODate("2016-06-28T12:17:46.982Z")
    }
},{$pull: {
    "history": {
        time: {
            $gte: ISODate("2016-06-28T12:17:46.982Z")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

but then I get errors like

```
Unsupported projection option: $pull: { history: { time: { $gte: new Date(1467116266982) } } }
```

Does anyone know how I could realize this query? I'm working now for days on this and couldn't find any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use the aggregation framework :

```
db.task.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id : ObjectId("5772ca87439632101510fa6b")}},
    {$unwind : "$history"},
    {$match :{"history.time" : 
              {
                  $lte: ISODate("2016-06-30T12:17:46.982Z"),
                  $gte: ISODate("2016-06-01T12:17:46.982Z")
              }
             }
    },
    {$group:
     {
         _id:"$_id",
         history: { $push:  { status: "$history.status", time: "$history.time" } }
     }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. But this doesn't do the thing I want. I want to keep them in their parent object on requesting. This is giving me an array of objects (nested ones) which matches. :/ Other option would be: Getting the newest object of a parent. (I think this would be even better)

Comment: To keep them in their parent you can use the "$group" operator. I edited the answer, tell me if it's what you want.

Comment: Yes. After I've removed $gte it worked for me. Thank you very much. May you tell me how to get ONLY the latest (by date the latest) object of a nested array too?

Comment: You are welcome ;)To get the "latest by date"  you can do something like that  : db.task.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id : ObjectId("5772ca87439632101510fa6b")}},
    {$unwind : "$history"},
    {$sort : {"history.time" : -1}},
    {$limit : 1},
]);